# IE 6 Debug Help!

Tags: jquery, debugging, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I just uploaded my site to the server, and it is working perfectly in Firefox and IE8, but not IE6 (have not tested in IE 7)...

Here is the address:  http://hqinternetsolutions.com/fullservice/index.html

There are two problems on the homepage that I cant seem to figure out. The header (which uses jquery to shift the images) appears far to the right. It seems like it aligns correctly and when the browser loads the js file, it readjusts the position. Any ideas?

Secondly, the sidebar has space to the right of it. It is floated left, but there are no margins. What could be causing this space?

Any help would be great!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your including plugins before the actual jquery core so you are getting an error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simpleswap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Ensure jQuery is first or before any jQuery plugins.

Can you fix this first then we can see what is wrong after.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/